# Marko in expressjs throwing not a function error

Tags: node.js, express, marko

Hi I ran this example on my machine and it says `markoExpress()` is not a function. Any ideas ? This is example from https://markojs.com/docs/express/

```
require("@marko/compiler/register"); // Allow Node.js to require and load `.marko` files

var express = require("express");
var markoExpress = require("@marko/express");
var template = require("./template");

var app = express();

app.use(markoExpress()); //enable res.marko(template, data)

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.marko(template, {
    name: "Frank",
    count: 30,
    colors: ["red", "green", "blue"]
  });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `@marko/express` is authored as an es module and the commonjs export for it exposes a `.default` property.

If consuming from commonjs you must do something like the following:

```js
const markoExpress = require('@marko/express').default;
```